# Clear cache when Logout ionic 2

Tags: authentication, caching, ionic2

i have a case,
i have 2 different account for login, i have profile page,and i can change my name in my profile page, and success, but when i logout and try to login again with different account to see different data in profile page it wasn't Change, it still  display data from the previous account, but when I clear it manually the cache, the data it's updated

how to automatically clear cache when user logout ?

this is my logout at auth-data.ts

```html
logoutUser()
  {
    return this.fireAuth.signOut();
  }
```

logout at home.ts

```html
logoutUser(){
  this.authData.logoutUser().then(() => {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that saves the name to Firebase?